# I tried to run the App, But Gradle is throwing this error

Tags: android, flutter, android-native-library

`
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/theroushan/Documents/NextSchool/android/app/build.gradle' line: 32
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_4a37y44n4qcdao4l4d5njw5b5.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_4a37y44n4qcdao4l4d5njw5b5$_run_closure2) values: [build_4a37y44n4qcdao4l4d5njw5b5$_run_closure2@73288fd8]

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

I tried to run the app, but I am getting this error in flutter?

Comment: please share your build.gradle file
/Users/theroushan/Documents/NextSchool/android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.